# c++ OCR Extracting digitsfrom an Image

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract, opencv3.0, xcode7.2

I have been trying to solve this issue for days. Here is an image.

[image]

I want to get digits from this image.

I tried background subtraction and partition image in segments so as to compare templates. But result is

```
111117
```

Along with this i tried Tesseract API and it even refused to give me any output. At one point i got "GALLONS" as a output. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: No chance that Tesseract will read those numbers. You could preprocess this image, but some naive preprocessing wouldn't work on the next image anyway. You have quite a tag soup.